# Unable to get $scope property value in angular

Tags: angularjs

**1. app.js**

```
var appProfileDetails = angular.module('profileDetailsApp', ['ngMaterial','ngAria','ngAnimate','ngRoute' ]);
```

**2. contactController.js**

```
appProfileDetails.controller('contactController', function($scope) {

    $scope.msg= function(){
        alert($scope.emailId);
    };


});
```

**3. html code**

```
<div style="height:55px;" ng-app="profileDetailsApp" ng-controller="contactController">
            <md-input-container > 
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="emailId" ng-model="emailId" > 
             </md-input-container>
    </div>


<md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="msg()" >Next</md-button>
```

Comment: please provide proper problem description when posting a question

Answer (score 0):

Its because your click is outside the scope of your `controller`. Put your button inside the `div` of `controller`. You are binding the function with the `scope` object inside the `contactController`but using outside the scope of controller in the `html.`

```
<div style="height:55px;" ng-app="profileDetailsApp" ng-controller="contactController">
            <md-input-container > 
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="emailId" ng-model="emailId" > 
             </md-input-container>
    <md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="msg()" >Next</md-button>
    </div>
```

Comment: but from the code you can see that <md-button> tag is inside the <div> tag.

Comment: @SanjayIzardar no it is not in the html shown in question. Also never use primitive in `ng-model`...always always use object